# Escribir en una ventana secundaria

Tags: javascript

Lo que quiero hacer es un document.write() en la ventana principal, y otro en la ventana secundaria que se abre. Sé que será una tontería pero llevo ya un rato y no soy capaz.

Lo que yo estoy haciendo es algo así, pero está claro que no funciona:

```html
<doctype HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <title></title>
  <style>
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   
   var subventana=window.open("index.html", "", "height=600, width=800");
   //sub_ventana.moveTo(0,0);
   subventana.resizeTo(800,600);
   document.write("<h1>Hola1</h1><br />");

   function realizar(){

    subventana.document.write("<h3>Hola2</h3><br />");

   }

   realizar();

  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: He creado `index.html` totalmente vacio y un archivo `test.html` donde copie y pegue el código. Cuando lo ejecuto, por ejemplo, `http://localhost/test.html`, funciona correctamente. ¿Como estas ejecutando el archivo que contiene este código?

Answer (score 1):

Si se puede solo le deje vacío el nombre del archivo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <title></title>
        <style>
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //En lugar de index.html lo dejé vacío 
            var subventana=window.open("", "", "height=600, width=800");
            subventana.resizeTo(800,600);
            document.write("<h1>Hola1</h1><br />");
            function realizar(){
                //Aquí agregué un div en la nuea ventana que es donde escribo el mensaje.
                subventana.document.write("<div id='hello'>Hola2<div>");
            }
            realizar();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Una recomendación cuando formules preguntas trata de ser más específico en el error para que los demás podamos ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente el navegador que estas usando no te muestra bien el resultado porque la etiqueta de tu html estaba mal o si no es porque te esta bloqueando por el tema de los popups. Fijate si te bloquea.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <title></title>
        <style>
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var subventana=window.open("index.html", "", "height=600, width=800");
            //sub_ventana.moveTo(0,0);
            subventana.resizeTo(800,600);
            document.write("<h1>Hola1</h1><br />");

            function realizar(){

                subventana.document.write("<h3>Hola2</h3><br />");

            }

            realizar();

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```